# Why does jQuery run this code three times?

Tags: jquery

I have this [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9606/):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //First bracket detection
  var string = $.trim($('p').text());
  string = string.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, "<span>$1</span>");
  $('p').html(string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> width (10mm) </p>
<p> width (10mm) </p>
<p> width (10mm) </p>
```

As you can see the items are duplicated. Each item appears 3 times, how can I do it only once?

Comment: use `.text` instead of `.html` to change text - also would advice against naming the variable string, change to something like `str`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to replace the content of paragraph in its context.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    //First bracket detection
    var string = $.trim($(this).text());
    string = string.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, "<span>$1</span>");
    $(this).html(string);
  })
});
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>width (10mm)</p>
<p>width (10mm)</p>
<p>width (10mm)</p>
```